# SASS syntax highlighting does not work when bundle is installed along with HAML's in Textmate?

Tags: textmate, haml, sass, textmatebundles

I've encountered this issue on two different machines and can't figure out what the cause is.

SASS syntax highlighting works fine in TextMate when I install a SASS bundle like [this](http://github.com/seaofclouds/sass-textmate-bundle). However, when I also install a HAML bundle, like [this one](http://github.com/handcrafted/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle), SASS code reverts to plain text color.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of bundles out there, all with the same lousy result.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the *.sass extention was somehow associated with HAML files. When I reverted it to SASS in the status bar of TextMate, things went back to normal. Quite inane.